# Communications Link Error - MySQL Timeout

Tags: java, mysql

I'm getting a communications link error after about 5 minutes of a MySQL database connection being open (MySQL Connector) and I thought it might be due to if no activity happens on a TCP connection in 5 minutes the connection ends.

I tried to change the timeout:

```
 int val = new BigDecimal("7.2e+6").intValue(); // Set default timeout to 2 hours
 con.setNetworkTimeout(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1), val);
```

which doesn't throw any errors so I guess its accepted the 2 hour time but i'm still getting the communications link error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 379,400 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 379,752 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1129)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2598)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
at createArticle.ArticleSelectConnect.UploadArticleProcess(ArticleSelectConnect.java:61)
at createArticle.CreateArticleController.UploadArticle(CreateArticleController.java:208)
at createArticle.CreateArticleController.SubmitArticle(CreateArticleController.java:64)
at createArticle.CreateArticleToolbar$1.run(CreateArticleToolbar.java:169)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3968)
... 9 more
```

Does anyone know what I can do so I can have a connection open in the background doing nothing for a while? - If i just send some data straight away (within about 5 minutes) it works fine.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to manage the connections manually?  Why not use a connection pool and configure it to [test the connections periodically](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#idleConnectionTestPeriod) in the background, thus keeping the TCP connection open?

Comment: Never heard of it before, i'll look into it thanks